# Two-way binding in custom component not working

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've created a component like this:

**templates/components/files-dropzone.hbs**

```
<p>Awesome text</p>
<textarea id="drop-textarea" rows="10" cols="50">
  {{value}}
</textarea>
```

**components/files-dropzone.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  value: '',

  valueChanged: function() {
    console.log("yup")  // is never triggered
  }.observes('value'),
})
```

I'm using this component like this in another template:

```
<div class="large-7 columns padding-left-reset"
  {{files-dropzone value=body}}
</div>
```

While the textarea contains the correct value for body when I load the page it doesn't bind it. I'm observing body and it doesn't change when I change the text inside the textarea.

EDIT: The value-attribute in the component itself doesn't change as well

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that Ember knows that it should bind the {{value}} to the text area.

It should work, using the textarea helper:

```
{{textarea value=value id="drop-textarea" rows="10" cols="50"}}
```

Do you want to adapt the behaviour of the text area in some way?

Comment: Yeah what I want is have a component which contains a {{textarea}} along with some other elements. Therefore I can't simply extend Ember.Textarea. Incorporating the textarea helper like you suggested in order to get the binding worked though. Thanks a lot.